# Dailymotion OAuth2 - Connect with Google+

Tags: dailymotion-api

When trying to authorize an application to access a Dailymotion user's account using OAuth 2, the authorization prompt shows and allows the user to log in with his credentials, or with his facebook account. 
However, there is no option to connect with Google+.
Is there a way to do so ?